# How to disable printing the Logback pattern in log files

Tags: logback

I noticed that [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) prints the pattern that it uses to format the log entries at the top of every log file.

For instance, I see this at the top of each log file:

```
#logback.classic pattern: %d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `outputPatternAsPresentationHeader` to false would work. However, the issue is addressed in [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) version 1.0.3 where `outputPatternAsPresentationHeader` is set to false by default.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem was [answered on the logback-user mailing list](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2012-May/003103.html).

I added this:

```
<outputPatternAsPresentationHeader>false</outputPatternAsPresentationHeader>
```

To the `<encoder>` element, below the `<pattern>` element, and my problem was solved!